# Reduce the size of carousal elements in small viewport wordpress. Used Elementor Plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uuebr.png)

As can be seen in the image. I want to make the elements present the carousal slider adjust to the viewport in samsung galaxy fold.

The viewport is 280*653

Why does the slider look the way it does?

Here is the link of my website

https://sviboindustries.in/

Please check why the webiste looks the way it does in samsung galaxy fold.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)

Comment: Do provide a minimal reproducible feature for your issue. Provide relevant code snippets and a sample expected UI (how are you expecting it to be).
Ping me once you are done with the changes